# Lotus Notes Java program to access $Revisions columns

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I am very new to lotus notes and java.
I am trying to get all documents which are modified by specific time.
I can not use getallmodifieddocuments because , notes version R5.

I am trying to get it as follows:

```
String query = Select Form = Protocol & ( last value from $revision ) > input datetime stamp

DocumentCollection dc = db.search ( query );
```

Then get all documents and process them.

Is it possible.

1. I can not get to $revision value to get print by getitemvaluestring ( $revision )
2. Is query even possible to implement?

I will appreciate if any other way !

Answer (score 3):

The Notes formula language has a built in formula for accessing the last modified date of a document:  [@Modified](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_MODIFIED.html)

Or if you have a reference to the document from Java, the getLastModified() method should get you that information.

Your query could be:

```
String query = "Form = ""Protocol"" & @Modified > @TextToTime(""1/1/1970"") "
```

Comment: Thanks so much.

I dont want to use getlastmodified() , i dont want to get to every document and perform that comparison. Just want to select modified time over input time stamp.

Thanks for your help that query helped.

Comment: @Prajakta, when it's done in the query, you arne't getting each document and then doing the comparison.